# Как получить цвет элемента QLabel (или любого другого) в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Стоит такая задача:
Установить цвет background-color на QLabel при помощи QColorDialog. После нужно проверить, имеет ли QLabel, например, красный или зелёный цвета. Проблема состоит в том, что я не знаю, как мне определить текущий цвет "бэкграунда" виджета, чтобы в последующем сравнивать его. 
P.S. Я знаю, что можно после установки цвета просто использовать color.name(), ведь  его значение и будет текущим цветом. Но с этим вариантом возникали проблемы, поэтому, я хотел бы узнать, возможно ли получить текущий background-color виджета QLabel в PyQt5?

---

Вопрос решён! `label.palette().color(QPalette.Window)` Спасибо @Alexander Chernin ^_^

Comment: Добавить пожалуйста пример, который у вас есть.

Comment: Что-то типа `label.palette().color(QPalette.Window)`

Comment: `labelqss = label.styleSheet()`

Comment: Alexandr Chernin, спасибо!

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, оформите как ответ :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так:

```
label.palette().color(QPalette.Window)
```