# Как узнать цвет виджета?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qpalette, qcolor

Как сравнить цвет `QLabel` с **`rgb(45,45,45)`**?

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45,45,45)")
        #If цвет self.label == rgb(45,45,45):
               print("1")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вот схожий с вашим [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1044802/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-qlabel-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-pyqt5), на который дали ответ, это то, что вы искали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, ответ @SergeyTatarincev правильный. Но чтобы продемонстрировать его на вашем примере, нужно выполнить эти действия через мгновение, т.е. дать возмлжность окну отрисоваться.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.label = QLabel('Hello World', self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45); 
            color: #fff;
        """)

        # дайте возможность окну отрисоваться        
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.get_color)

    def get_color(self):
        palette = self.label.palette()
        color = palette.color(QPalette.Window)
        if color == QColor(45, 45, 45):
            print(f'{color.getRgb()} или {color.name()}')
        else:
            print('not equal')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

на вопрос как получить цвет ответ дан [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1345278/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-qpalette-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-qapplication-%D0%B2-pyqt5/1345287#1345287)

сравнить полученный цвет можно следующим образом

```
palette = self.label.palette()
color = palette.color(QPalette.Window)
if color == QColor(45,45,45):
    print('equal')
else:
    print('not equal')
```

Answer (score -1):

Я не знаю PyQt но в таких случаях я ставлю метод dict и смотрю все функции методы и скорее всего она будет называться color или background

Должно получиться

self.label.color

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Тут форум на русском

Comment: Igor junior-senior ваш ответ неправильный.